# Err:508 in formula written with Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl, libreoffice-calc

I have this script:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = 1 #any value
ws['B1'] = 0 #any value
ws['C1'] = 3 #any value
ws['D1'] = 0 #any value
ws['E1'] = "= IF(A1<>0;A1;1) * IF(B1<>0;B1;1) * IF(C1<>0;C1;1) * IF(D1<>0;D1;1)"
wb.save('error.xlsx')
```

When I open the file with LibreOffice Calc, I see **Err:508** in `E` column:

[image: Err:508]

However, if I edit the formula in the command line, without changing nothing (i.e. add an space or erase any character and write the same again) the formula works.

Any idea where is the mistake?

Comment: Read https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-formulae carefully.

Comment: Thx. I had read this part but I never kept in mind the issue about functions, commas and semi-colons ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching in https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-formulae as @Charlie Clark suggested, it says:

> Warning
>
> NB you must use the English name for a function and function arguments must be separated by commas and not other punctuation such as semi-colons.`

so this line:

```
ws['E1'] = "= IF(A1<>0;A1;1) * IF(B1<>0;B1;1) * IF(C1<>0;C1;1) * IF(D1<>0;D1;1)"
```

must be:

```
ws['E1'] = "= IF(A1<>0,A1,1) * IF(B1<>0,B1,1) * IF(C1<>0,C1,1) * IF(D1<>0,D1,1)"
```

Comment: Just a small remark: the new link to the docs is https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/simple_formulae.html nowadays.